# Lost on MySQL query

Tags: mysql, view

I've done some research and I know about building views but I feel like what I am trying to accomplish may not be possible without creating a hard coded table of information..Below is what I am trying to accomplish

```
Table 1 
ID
1
2
3
4
5

Table 2
ID     DATE
1      4/23/2014
1      5/10/2014
2      4/15/2014
5      12/13/2013
3      3/15/2014
```

What I am wanting to do is compose a query that will start with the data in table one as it contains all possible ID's, I want to join this data with the data from table 2 based on the ID field, but the key is I will be passing in a date argument that will be filtering the data based on month and year as well.  What I need to happen is if an ID in table one does not have a record in Table 2 for a given month I need a null record to be created.  The issue I am running into is not having a single null record no matter what for each ID in table one being put into the view which below I explain why I need this.  Here is the view I am getting with just typical left join:

```
Table 3 (View or just a general query joining the above tables)
ID     DATE
1      4/23/2014
1      5/10/2014
2      4/15/2014
5      12/13/2013
3      3/15/2014
4      null
```

Now its easy to see if I pulled for this data for the month/year of 4/2014 or null I would get

```
ID     DATE
1      4/23/2014
2      4/15/2014
4      null
```

What I am looking to get (which I realize is impossible from the data in this view) is:

```
ID     DATE
1      4/23/2014
2      4/15/2014
4      null
3      null
5      null
```

So is there a way to create these rows in a view dynamically so that when I pass in my date argument I will get the desired results?  One thing I just thought of right this second would be to create a view with just the ID's from table 1 and a null date field and possibly union the two views together?  Or could a Union be used in building the initial view to get the desired results?  Once I have the data in the final view (or pulling it with the correct query in general) I will be able to accomplish my final task of building reports based on the data.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you've filtered with the where clause. Put your filter conditions in the ON clause of your left join.

Comment: I feel ridiculous for not trying this in the first place!  Thank you for your quick response!